# Date formatting not working for datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using datepicker to allow user to select a date. I can't the change the format.

I've been trying based on the example found here like dateFormat and even format but it still doesn't work

This is how I add the datepicker to my table

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnView").click(function() {

         if (!Array.isArray(aItems) || !aItems.length) {

                document.getElementById('btnSubmit').style.visibility = 'hidden';               
            }

         else {     

             document.getElementById('btnSubmit').style.visibility = 'visible';  
            var html2 = '';
            $.each(aItems, function(i, post) {

                let oQtyModal = "itemqtymodal_" + i;
                let oDate = "iDate_" + i;

                html2 += '<tr>';
                html2 += '<td>' + post["NEW_ITEM-MATNR"] + '</td>';
                html2 += '<td>' + post["NEW_ITEM-MATGROUP"] + '</td>';
                html2 += '<td>' + post["NEW_ITEM-DESCRIPTION"] + '</td>';
                html2 += '<td>' + post["NEW_ITEM-PRICE"] + '</td>';
                //html2 += '<td>' + post["NEW_ITEM-QUANTITY"] + '</td>';
                html2 += '<td>'  + '<input type="text"' + 'onchange="getQty(this)"' + 'name="' + oQtyModal + '"' + 'id="' + oQtyModal + '"' + 'value='+post["NEW_ITEM-QUANTITY"]+'>' + '</td>';
                html2 += '<td align="center">' + post["NEW_ITEM-UNIT"] + '</td>';
                html2 += '<td>' + post["NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD1"] + '</td>';
                html2 += '<td>' + '<input type="text"' + 'class="datepicker"' + 'id="' + oDate + '"' + 'value='+post["NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD2"]+'>' + '<i class="far fa-calendar-alt" style=' + 'font-size:24px;color:#1E90FF' + '></i></></td>';
                html2 += '<td>' + '<input type="button" onClick="deleteProduct(this)" value="Delete Item" />' + '</td>';
                html2 += '</tr>';           
                $('#table2 tbody').html(html2);
              });
            var dateToday = new Date();
            $('.datepicker').datepicker(
              { 

                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                autoclose: true,
                startDate: new Date()
              });           
            }
    });
});
```

My main code to get the date data and updating my array is below

```
$(document).on("change", ".datepicker", function(){
    var oDate = $(this);
    var aIndex = oDate[0].id.split('_');
    aItems[aIndex[1]]["NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD2"] = document.getElementById(oDate[0].id).value

 });
```

EDIT: Its working now. Code has been updated above.

Comment: You shouldn't initialize datepicker twice. Remove `$(this).datepicker();` line

Answer (score 0):

here is the sample: https://jsfiddle.net/3mygd26w/
HTML

```
Date Picker on input field: <input type="text" id="date1" name="date1"/> <br/>

Date Picker on input field: <input type="text" id="date2" name="date2"/> <br/>

Date Picker on input field: <input type="text" id="date3" name="dat3"/> <br/>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#date1').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: "m/d/yy"
});
$('#date2').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: "d/m/yy"
});
$('#date3').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy"
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm having multiple datepicker without hardcoding. I've updated my first post to show you guys how I add the datepicker to my table

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a framework try to empty the cache after any template change, if you are using symfony check you are writting in the main file and not in the one in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to give more detailed answer. Your mistake is initialising Datepicker twice. First time - without `dateFormat`. When you call it second time with `dateFormat` it's already initialised. Instead you should assign it to a variable if you plan to reuse same Datepicker object.

**Updated to reflect question code change**

```
$('input.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'});
```

Call this initialisation code only *once*, *after* you've inserted your whole table.

Note: for userdate it's better to listen on `change` event, not on `focus`, otherwise you'll stick to previous value

```
$('input.datepicker').change(function(){
  var selectedDate = $(this).val();
  console.log(selectedDate);
})
```

Comment: Hi Evgenii, thanks I've tried that but the format is still not taking into effect. I will update my first post to show you what I've done to add the datepicker

Comment: Now it's even worse than it was before. You don't need Vanilla JS methods if you're already using jQuery. You're initialising Datepicker for all inputs in every loop cycle. Take initialiasition outside the loop. Do it only once with Date format object attached. Also I've updated my answer to include listening on change event example.

Comment: Hey bro, I've added the initialisation after my loop. (actually, even previous code. the initialisation was after the for loop. I added  `$('input.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'});` but the format is still mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: I've updated my first post to show a bigger picture of how I added the datepicker. strangely the autoclose is working after i select a date but the format is still not changing :(

Comment: Could you please cut `onchange` and `value` attributes from input tag for debug purposes? And check if problem still here or not

Comment: hey man, I've managed to get the format to work. I added an icon as well. I've updated my codes in the first post. So far so good! thanks for your help bro. really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

use jquery

```
 <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
  });
  </script>
```

reference- https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the guidance. I've updated my first post to show what I've done.